# Data is not parsing into map through fromJson function

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, http

I am trying to fetch data from the API but when I parse data through fromjson then data is not returning please fix this issue.

this is Function calling API and having issue in this function when I am parsing data through model. I have given code of service class in which i am using API to fetch data of inventory and i  have given modal class and json response through API

```
 Future<List<Inventory>> requestInventory(
      String accessToken, String userId) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('${AppUrl.getInventory}/$userId'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'
        });

     late List<Inventory> list=[];

    //  List<Inventory>? list;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var value = jsonDecode(response.body);

      //old
      // var data = value['data']['inventory'];

          var data = value['details']['data']['user']['inventory'];

          print("data in inventory service ->>>> $data");

      if (data != null || data != []) {
        list= data.map<Inventory>((json) => Inventory.fromJson(json)).toList();
        print('inventory service list is ::::::::::::::::::::::: $list');
        return list;
      } else {
        return list = [];
      }

      // list = data.map<Inventory>((json) => Inventory.fromJson(json)).toList();
      // return list;

    } else {
      return list = [];
    }
  }
```

This is my My Model Class

```
class GetInventory {
  GetInventory({
      String? details, 
      Data? data,}){
    _details = details;
    _data = data;
}

  GetInventory.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _details = json['details'];
    _data = json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }
  String? _details;
  Data? _data;
GetInventory copyWith({  String? details,
  Data? data,
}) => GetInventory(  details: details ?? _details,
  data: data ?? _data,
);
  String? get details => _details;
  Data? get data => _data;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['details'] = _details;
    if (_data != null) {
      map['data'] = _data?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }

}



class Data {
  Data({
      User? user, 
      List<Posts>? posts,}){
    _user = user;
    _posts = posts;
}

  Data.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _user = json['user'] != null ? User.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
    if (json['posts'] != null) {
      _posts = [];
      json['posts'].forEach((v) {
        _posts?.add(Posts.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  User? _user;
  List<Posts>? _posts;
Data copyWith({  User? user,
  List<Posts>? posts,
}) => Data(  user: user ?? _user,
  posts: posts ?? _posts,
);
  User? get user => _user;
  List<Posts>? get posts => _posts;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_user != null) {
      map['user'] = _user?.toJson();
    }
    if (_posts != null) {
      map['posts'] = _posts?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }

}



class Posts {
  Posts({
      List<TradeWithPictures>? tradeWithPictures, 
      List<String>? tags, 
      List<Pictures>? pictures, 
      List<Comments>? comments, 
      String? id, 
      String? title, 
      String? description, 
      String? category, 
      String? subCategory, 
      String? condition, 
      String? user, 
      String? createdAt, 
      String? updatedAt,}){
    _tradeWithPictures = tradeWithPictures;
    _tags = tags;
    _pictures = pictures;
    _comments = comments;
    _id = id;
    _title = title;
    _description = description;
    _category = category;
    _subCategory = subCategory;
    _condition = condition;
    _user = user;
    _createdAt = createdAt;
    _updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

  Posts.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    if (json['tradeWithPictures'] != null) {
      _tradeWithPictures = [];
      json['tradeWithPictures'].forEach((v) {
        _tradeWithPictures?.add(TradeWithPictures.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _tags = json['tags'] != null ? json['tags'].cast<String>() : [];
    if (json['pictures'] != null) {
      _pictures = [];
      json['pictures'].forEach((v) {
        _pictures?.add(Pictures.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['comments'] != null) {
      _comments = [];
      json['comments'].forEach((v) {
        _comments?.add(Comments.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _id = json['_id'];
    _title = json['title'];
    _description = json['description'];
    _category = json['category'];
    _subCategory = json['subCategory'];
    _condition = json['condition'];
    _user = json['user'];
    _createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    _updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
  }
  List<TradeWithPictures>? _tradeWithPictures;
  List<String>? _tags;
  List<Pictures>? _pictures;
  List<Comments>? _comments;
  String? _id;
  String? _title;
  String? _description;
  String? _category;
  String? _subCategory;
  String? _condition;
  String? _user;
  String? _createdAt;
  String? _updatedAt;
Posts copyWith({  List<TradeWithPictures>? tradeWithPictures,
  List<String>? tags,
  List<Pictures>? pictures,
  List<Comments>? comments,
  String? id,
  String? title,
  String? description,
  String? category,
  String? subCategory,
  String? condition,
  String? user,
  String? createdAt,
  String? updatedAt,
}) => Posts(  tradeWithPictures: tradeWithPictures ?? _tradeWithPictures,
  tags: tags ?? _tags,
  pictures: pictures ?? _pictures,
  comments: comments ?? _comments,
  id: id ?? _id,
  title: title ?? _title,
  description: description ?? _description,
  category: category ?? _category,
  subCategory: subCategory ?? _subCategory,
  condition: condition ?? _condition,
  user: user ?? _user,
  createdAt: createdAt ?? _createdAt,
  updatedAt: updatedAt ?? _updatedAt,
);
  List<TradeWithPictures>? get tradeWithPictures => _tradeWithPictures;
  List<String>? get tags => _tags;
  List<Pictures>? get pictures => _pictures;
  List<Comments>? get comments => _comments;
  String? get id => _id;
  String? get title => _title;
  String? get description => _description;
  String? get category => _category;
  String? get subCategory => _subCategory;
  String? get condition => _condition;
  String? get user => _user;
  String? get createdAt => _createdAt;
  String? get updatedAt => _updatedAt;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (_tradeWithPictures != null) {
      map['tradeWithPictures'] = _tradeWithPictures?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['tags'] = _tags;
    if (_pictures != null) {
      map['pictures'] = _pictures?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (_comments != null) {
      map['comments'] = _comments?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['_id'] = _id;
    map['title'] = _title;
    map['description'] = _description;
    map['category'] = _category;
    map['subCategory'] = _subCategory;
    map['condition'] = _condition;
    map['user'] = _user;
    map['createdAt'] = _createdAt;
    map['updatedAt'] = _updatedAt;
    return map;
  }

}



class Comments {
  Comments({
      String? text, 
      Profile? profile,}){
    _text = text;
    _profile = profile;
}

  Comments.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _text = json['text'];
    _profile = json['profile'] != null ? Profile.fromJson(json['profile']) : null;
  }
  String? _text;
  Profile? _profile;
Comments copyWith({  String? text,
  Profile? profile,
}) => Comments(  text: text ?? _text,
  profile: profile ?? _profile,
);
  String? get text => _text;
  Profile? get profile => _profile;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['text'] = _text;
    if (_profile != null) {
      map['profile'] = _profile?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }

}


class Profile {
  Profile({
      String? role, 
      bool? banned, 
      dynamic bannedTill, 
      List<dynamic>? inventory, 
      String? fcmToken, 
      String? profilePictureURL, 
      String? id, 
      String? createdAt, 
      String? updatedAt, 
      String? firstName, 
      String? lastName,}){
    _role = role;
    _banned = banned;
    _bannedTill = bannedTill;
    _inventory = inventory;
    _fcmToken = fcmToken;
    _profilePictureURL = profilePictureURL;
    _id = id;
    _createdAt = createdAt;
    _updatedAt = updatedAt;
    _firstName = firstName;
    _lastName = lastName;
}

  Profile.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _role = json['role'];
    _banned = json['banned'];
    _bannedTill = json['bannedTill'];
    if (json['inventory'] != null) {
      _inventory = [];
      json['inventory'].forEach((v) {
      //  _inventory?.add(dynamic.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _fcmToken = json['fcmToken'];
    _profilePictureURL = json['profilePictureURL'];
    _id = json['_id'];
    _createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    _updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    _firstName = json['firstName'];
    _lastName = json['lastName'];
  }
  String? _role;
  bool? _banned;
  dynamic _bannedTill;
  List<dynamic>? _inventory;
  String? _fcmToken;
  String? _profilePictureURL;
  String? _id;
  String? _createdAt;
  String? _updatedAt;
  String? _firstName;
  String? _lastName;
Profile copyWith({  String? role,
  bool? banned,
  dynamic bannedTill,
  List<dynamic>? inventory,
  String? fcmToken,
  String? profilePictureURL,
  String? id,
  String? createdAt,
  String? updatedAt,
  String? firstName,
  String? lastName,
}) => Profile(  role: role ?? _role,
  banned: banned ?? _banned,
  bannedTill: bannedTill ?? _bannedTill,
  inventory: inventory ?? _inventory,
  fcmToken: fcmToken ?? _fcmToken,
  profilePictureURL: profilePictureURL ?? _profilePictureURL,
  id: id ?? _id,
  createdAt: createdAt ?? _createdAt,
  updatedAt: updatedAt ?? _updatedAt,
  firstName: firstName ?? _firstName,
  lastName: lastName ?? _lastName,
);
  String? get role => _role;
  bool? get banned => _banned;
  dynamic get bannedTill => _bannedTill;
  List<dynamic>? get inventory => _inventory;
  String? get fcmToken => _fcmToken;
  String? get profilePictureURL => _profilePictureURL;
  String? get id => _id;
  String? get createdAt => _createdAt;
  String? get updatedAt => _updatedAt;
  String? get firstName => _firstName;
  String? get lastName => _lastName;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['role'] = _role;
    map['banned'] = _banned;
    map['bannedTill'] = _bannedTill;
    if (_inventory != null) {
      map['inventory'] = _inventory?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['fcmToken'] = _fcmToken;
    map['profilePictureURL'] = _profilePictureURL;
    map['_id'] = _id;
    map['createdAt'] = _createdAt;
    map['updatedAt'] = _updatedAt;
    map['firstName'] = _firstName;
    map['lastName'] = _lastName;
    return map;
  }

}



class Pictures {
  Pictures({
      String? publicID, 
      String? url,}){
    _publicID = publicID;
    _url = url;
}

  Pictures.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _publicID = json['publicID'];
    _url = json['url'];
  }
  String? _publicID;
  String? _url;
Pictures copyWith({  String? publicID,
  String? url,
}) => Pictures(  publicID: publicID ?? _publicID,
  url: url ?? _url,
);
  String? get publicID => _publicID;
  String? get url => _url;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['publicID'] = _publicID;
    map['url'] = _url;
    return map;
  }

}

/// publicID : "bartermade/post-pictures/oqzvs8cnioj2yncpembd"
/// url : "https://res.cloudinary.com/dtksvfjsi/image/upload/v1649202575/bartermade/post-pictures/oqzvs8cnioj2yncpembd.jpg"

class TradeWithPictures {
  TradeWithPictures({
      String? publicID, 
      String? url,}){
    _publicID = publicID;
    _url = url;
}

  TradeWithPictures.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _publicID = json['publicID'];
    _url = json['url'];
  }
  String? _publicID;
  String? _url;
TradeWithPictures copyWith({  String? publicID,
  String? url,
}) => TradeWithPictures(  publicID: publicID ?? _publicID,
  url: url ?? _url,
);
  String? get publicID => _publicID;
  String? get url => _url;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['publicID'] = _publicID;
    map['url'] = _url;
    return map;
  }

}


class User {
  User({
      String? role, 
      bool? banned, 
      dynamic bannedTill, 
      List<Inventory>? inventory, 
      dynamic fcmToken, 
      String? profilePictureURL, 
      String? id, 
      String? createdAt, 
      String? updatedAt, 
      String? firstName, 
      String? lastName,}){
    _role = role;
    _banned = banned;
    _bannedTill = bannedTill;
    _inventory = inventory;
    _fcmToken = fcmToken;
    _profilePictureURL = profilePictureURL;
    _id = id;
    _createdAt = createdAt;
    _updatedAt = updatedAt;
    _firstName = firstName;
    _lastName = lastName;
}

  User.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _role = json['role'];
    _banned = json['banned'];
    _bannedTill = json['bannedTill'];
    if (json['inventory'] != null) {
      _inventory = [];
      json['inventory'].forEach((v) {
        _inventory?.add(Inventory.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _fcmToken = json['fcmToken'];
    _profilePictureURL = json['profilePictureURL'];
    _id = json['_id'];
    _createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    _updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    _firstName = json['firstName'];
    _lastName = json['lastName'];
  }
  String? _role;
  bool? _banned;
  dynamic _bannedTill;
  List<Inventory>? _inventory;
  dynamic _fcmToken;
  String? _profilePictureURL;
  String? _id;
  String? _createdAt;
  String? _updatedAt;
  String? _firstName;
  String? _lastName;
User copyWith({  String? role,
  bool? banned,
  dynamic bannedTill,
  List<Inventory>? inventory,
  dynamic fcmToken,
  String? profilePictureURL,
  String? id,
  String? createdAt,
  String? updatedAt,
  String? firstName,
  String? lastName,
}) => User(  role: role ?? _role,
  banned: banned ?? _banned,
  bannedTill: bannedTill ?? _bannedTill,
  inventory: inventory ?? _inventory,
  fcmToken: fcmToken ?? _fcmToken,
  profilePictureURL: profilePictureURL ?? _profilePictureURL,
  id: id ?? _id,
  createdAt: createdAt ?? _createdAt,
  updatedAt: updatedAt ?? _updatedAt,
  firstName: firstName ?? _firstName,
  lastName: lastName ?? _lastName,
);
  String? get role => _role;
  bool? get banned => _banned;
  dynamic get bannedTill => _bannedTill;
  List<Inventory>? get inventory => _inventory;
  dynamic get fcmToken => _fcmToken;
  String? get profilePictureURL => _profilePictureURL;
  String? get id => _id;
  String? get createdAt => _createdAt;
  String? get updatedAt => _updatedAt;
  String? get firstName => _firstName;
  String? get lastName => _lastName;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['role'] = _role;
    map['banned'] = _banned;
    map['bannedTill'] = _bannedTill;
    if (_inventory != null) {
      map['inventory'] = _inventory?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['fcmToken'] = _fcmToken;
    map['profilePictureURL'] = _profilePictureURL;
    map['_id'] = _id;
    map['createdAt'] = _createdAt;
    map['updatedAt'] = _updatedAt;
    map['firstName'] = _firstName;
    map['lastName'] = _lastName;
    return map;
  }

}


class Inventory {
  Inventory({
      String? quantity, 
      String? description, 
      String? url,}){
    _quantity = quantity;
    _description = description;
    _url = url;
}

  Inventory.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _quantity = json['quantity'];
    _description = json['description'];
    _url = json['url'];
  }
  String? _quantity;
  String? _description;
  String? _url;
Inventory copyWith({  String? quantity,
  String? description,
  String? url,
}) => Inventory(  quantity: quantity ?? _quantity,
  description: description ?? _description,
  url: url ?? _url,
);
  String? get quantity => _quantity;
  String? get description => _description;
  String? get url => _url;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['quantity'] = _quantity;
    map['description'] = _description;
    map['url'] = _url;
    return map;
  }

}
```

and this is Json response

```
{
    "details": "got user successfully",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "role": "user",
            "banned": false,
            "bannedTill": null,
            "inventory": [
               
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hello",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "mobile",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "helpo ",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "desc",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "descc",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hellog",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "check blue",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "this is app inventory ",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "fhbbj",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "yuj",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hello",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "ghb",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "tctcct",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "Saad Ebad",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "vbvhh",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "Saad",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "saas",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hwhah",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "gbbhh",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hebsb",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "ndnsn",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hello brother ",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hfnfnf",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "ffg",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "ghh",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "hawa hawa",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "gggg",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "0",
                    "description": "Asif",
                    "url": "http://localhost/api/media/inventory-pictures/undefined"
                }
            ],
            "fcmToken": null,
            "profilePictureURL": "https://cdn.luxe.digital/media/2019/09/12090502/business-professional-dress-code-men-style-luxe-digital.jpg",
            "_id": "624bac63fbf73b08462af651",
            "createdAt": "2022-04-05T02:41:39.754Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-04-10T06:36:37.818Z",
            "firstName": "saad",
            "lastName": "ebad"
        },
        "posts": [
            {
                "tradeWithPictures": [
                    {
                        "publicID": "bartermade/post-pictures/oqzvs8cnioj2yncpembd",
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dtksvfjsi/image/upload/v1649202575/bartermade/post-pictures/oqzvs8cnioj2yncpembd.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "Camera",
                    "Mobile",
                    "Cycles"
                ],
                "pictures": [
                    {
                        "publicID": "bartermade/post-pictures/vuepwgaymffwhdvcz3lx",
                        "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dtksvfjsi/image/upload/v1649202573/bartermade/post-pictures/vuepwgaymffwhdvcz3lx.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "text": "bsbsn",
                        "profile": {
                            "role": "user",
                            "banned": false,
                            "bannedTill": null,
                            "inventory": [],
                            "fcmToken": "",
                            "profilePictureURL": "https://cdn.luxe.digital/media/2019/09/12090502/business-professional-dress-code-men-style-luxe-digital.jpg",
                            "_id": "624bac63fbf73b08462af651",
                            "createdAt": "2022-04-05T02:41:39.754Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-04-06T04:29:06.535Z",
                            "firstName": "saad",
                            "lastName": "ebad"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "624cd591fbf73b08462afb73",
                "title": "Infinix",
                "description": "Infinix note 8",
                "category": "mobiles",
                "subCategory": "smart phones",
                "condition": "Old",
                "user": "624bac63fbf73b08462af651",
                "createdAt": "2022-04-05T23:49:37.116Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-04-06T04:33:40.069Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the keys of the json used to get the inventory list. Try with this:

```
 var data = value['data']['user']['inventory'];
```